# With vue cli3, why can't I see my configureWebpack changes?

Tags: webpack, vue.js

Getting started with Vue cli 3. I've created a vue.config.js like this...

```
// vue.config.js
var path = require('path');
module.exports = {
  baseUrl: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
    ? '/production-sub-path/'
    : '\/mobileapp\/v\/',
  configureWebpack : {
    devServer:{
      headers: {
        'X-Custom-Foo': 'bar'
      },
      host:'notilusdev.dimosoftware.com'
    }
  }
}
```

I know it's working because the baseUrl property is picked up. But no matter what I put in configureWebpack, nothing changes.

I can do a vue-cli-service inspect, and I see my custom header as the last entry...

```
devServer: {
  headers: {
    'X-Custom-Foo': 'bar'
  },
  host: 'notilusdev.dimosoftware.com'
}
```

What might cause webpack to ignore this config? What can I put in there just to test that it's even working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [warning](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/webpack.html#simple-configuration) mentioned related to mutating some webpack options directly using `configureWebpack`.

> WARNING
>
> Some webpack options are set based on values in vue.config.js and
>   should not be mutated directly. For example, instead of modifying
>   output.path, you should use the outputDir option in vue.config.js;
>   instead of modifying output.publicPath, you should use the baseUrl
>   option in vue.config.js. This is because the values in vue.config.js
>   will be used in multiple places inside the config to ensure everything
>   works properly together.

There is a [`devServer`](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#devserver) option present you can use directly in **vue.config.js**. Use this option to modify options related to `webpack-dev-server`

```
// vue.config.js
var path = require("path");
module.exports = {
  baseUrl:
    process.env.NODE_ENV === "production"
      ? "/production-sub-path/"
      : "/mobileapp/v/",
  devServer: {
    headers: {
      "X-Custom-Foo": "bar"
    },
    host: "notilusdev.dimosoftware.com"
  }
};
```