# How to change host for vue-cli hot reload endpoint (sockjs)?

Tags: nginx, npm, vagrant, virtualbox, vue-cli-3

**What do I have**:

- `vue-cli` app running in virtual machine (`vue --version` 3.7.0)
- Laravel Homestead v8.3.2
- Vagrant 2.2.4
- VirtualBox
- Nginx

`vue.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    host: 'myvueapp.local',
    https: true
  }
}
```

Nginx config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name .myvueapp.local;
    root "/home/path/to/myvueapp.local/public";

    index index.html index.htm;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
        proxy_pass https://myvueapp.local:8080;
    }

    sendfile off;
}
```

`npm run serve` output:

```
Local: https://myvueapp.local:8080/
Network: https://myvueapp.local:8080/
```

**What do I do**:

I run `npm run serve` in my VM. I can access Vue app from my host machine by `myvueapp.local` in browser.

**What's my problem**:

Hot reload does not work. `sockjs` connection is calling not `myvueapp.local` but `myvueapp.local:8080`. So, I'm getting

> https://myvueapp.local:8080/sockjs-node/info?t=
>   net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Answer (score 0):

**You need a public property on your devServer, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50906833/with-vue-cli3-why-cant-i-see-my-configurewebpack-changes)**

Then, hot reloading will work in fallback (http polling) mode, but to properly get websockets working, you need to handle upgrade requests in your proxy server. [Here](https://gist.github.com/hhanh00/ddf3bf62294fc420a0de) is a script that solves the problem for express. You will need to port this to nginx. It's just the last part concerning upgrade requests that you're missing.

Comment: I'd like to keep my vue config as it is, modify only env settings (Nginx, Vagrant) if possible. I'm using Vagrant to make it possible to pull my project from git and do work without modifying the project itself.

Comment: Well that's never going to work, I suspect. The devServer needs to know its public address. Remember we're talking about a development environment. When you've built your app, you have a self-contained bundle that can be attacked however you want. Dev is a bit more fragile.